# Why am I receiving a Null Exception when using @Value Annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I switched from getting values by loading up the properties file and retrieve them to using @Value annotations. Right now I am able to print the values that I set. When I run my application I see the value, But when I open up localhost:8080 I receive a null exception.

**IndexController**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
     @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView getdata() throws IOException {
        AppPortList apL = new AppPortList();
        List<AppPortModel> apList = apL.getAppPortList();   
        Collections.sort(apList);

ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
    model.addObject("showap", apList);

    return model;
}
```

**Properties file**

```
APP_SERVERS=Server1@!Server1212@!Server12daa21@!Server21334
APP_SERVER_List=1020@!3011@!8080@!2020
```

//much more servers than this.

**Class that is having errors**

```
@Component
public class AppPortList {      

 @Value("#{'${APP_SERVERS}'.split('@!')}")
    private String[] apServerArray;
 @Value("#{'${APP_SERVER_List}'.split('@!')}")
    private String[] appServerPortsList;

@PostConstruct
public List<AppPortModel> getAppPortList() {
    try {
        System.out.println(apServerArray.length + "@@@@");
            for (int z = 0; z < apServerArray.length; z++) {                
                String apServer = apServerArray[z];
                String[] portListArray=appServerPortsList;
}catch {//stuff}
```

**Console Output**

```
16@@@@@
```

When I open local host I receive a null exception on Line 80. Which is my for Statement. "for (int z = 0; z < apServerArray.length; z++)" is coming up null.

**Running local Host Error**

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.spring.web.util.AppPortList.getAppPortList(AppPortList.java:82) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.spring.web.controller.IndexController.getdata(IndexController.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
```

**Attempt 2**

So I commented my for statment out and used System.out.println(apServerArray + "@@@@");

**Output 2**

```
 [Ljava.lang.String;@328b8745@@@@@
```

and when I ran my localhost I get null. So why does my console reads it when I run it then when I open localhost it becomes null?

```
  null@@@@@
```

Comment: try with `${APP_SERVERS:}` (add `:` before the closing accolade). Does it changes the behavior ?

Comment: No, same behavior.

Comment: Can you show how it is in your property file?

Comment: Also, my guess apServerArray and  appServerPortsList should be of type List<String>

Comment: When I switch to List<String>. it won't even print to console.

Comment: you can read it as a string and do the split in the postconstruct method. it is really tough tell what is going on. syntax looks correct.

Comment: Bharath what is confusing you? I can delete or add more cod to help clarify my problems. I can't split in below at @PostConstruct also gives me an error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing two things here:

You annotated `AppPortList` with `@Component`, so when you start your application, your **beans are created by the Spring container** and the `@PostConstruct` is called.
When a bean is created by Spring, it also injects values for the `@Value` annotations, so that's why you see the correct output in the `System.out.println()` inside your `@PostConstruct`.

However, in your controller you are using `new AppPortList()`. In this case you **created the beans by yourself** and you're not using the bean offered by the Spring container. In this case, the `@Value` annotation is not picked up, so the output is `null`.

The solution is simple, rather than using the `new` keyword, you have to use dependency injection. When you use dependency injection, the Spring container will look for an instance of the bean (which is has thanks to the `@Component` annotation) and it will inject it where you need it.

In your case you need it in your `IndexController`, so you'll have to change it a bit:

```java
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @Autowired
    private AppPortList apL; // Create this field with @Autowired annotation

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getdata() throws IOException {
        // Remove new AppPortList() and use field in stead
        List<AppPortModel> apList = apL.getAppPortList();   
        // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really have to avoid using "new".